# FFMpeg Concat error: [mxf @xxx] index entry xxx+ TemporalOffset 1 = xxx, which is out of bounds

Tags: ffmpeg, video, troubleshooting, concatenation

Use FFmpeg to concatenate broadcast files about 50 times a day.
Files are transcoded to XDCAMHD prior to being concatenated. This error occurs on 15% of all concats even if there is only 1 source file. Error occurs always at the end of the concat process at 100%, so no media is lost.

This is the simplified transcode command (filters are inserted depending if framerrate conversion, scaling and silent tracks is required):

```
-i "source" -acodec pcm_s24le -ac 1 -ar 48000 -codec:v mpeg2video -b:v 50M -minrate 50M -maxrate 50M  -bufsize 17825792 -rc_init_occupancy 17825792 -g 12 -bf 2 -non_linear_quant 1 -profile:v 0 -level:v 2 -aspect 16:9 -intra_vlc 1 -color_primaries bt709 -color_trc bt709 -colorspace bt709 -seq_disp_ext 1 -video_format component -color_range 1 -chroma_sample_location topleft -signal_standard 4 -dc 8 -qmin 3 -qmax 28 -alternate_scan 1 -flags +ilme+ildct -top 1 -pix_fmt yuv422p -field_order tt -dn -sn -map 0:v:0 -filter_complex "<pan-filters to create mono tracks>" <audio mapping> -vf "<scale-filter>,<framerate-conversion>" -bsf:v "filter_units=remove_types=178" -f mxf -y "transcode-destination.mxf"
```

This the concat command:

```
-f concat -i "concatlist.txt" -codec:a copy -codec:v copy -dn -sn -map 0:v -map 0:a -y "concat-destination.mxf"
```

I suspected first it had anything todo with open Gops in transcode. tried to add +cgop to the flags list but that did not had any effect.

So what is causing this error what can i do about it?

note: Using the 6.1.1 release build from Gyan.